# Assigning the Outlet from Different Class? (Core Plot)

Tags: xcode, class, core-plot, fatal-error, iboutlet

I have a class which is for bluetooth data receiving and I wonder to send the receiving data to class UIViewController and do the realtime plotting (CorePlot)

```
class BluetoothManager: NSObject {
   func dataReceiving(value: [Int]){
      MainController().plot(dataOne: [Int], dataTwo: [Int])
}
```

MainController class:

```
class MainController: UIViewController,CPTScatterPlotDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var graphView: CPTGraphHostingView!

    func plot(dataOne: [Int], dataTwo: [Int]){
        let newGraph = CPTXYGraph(frame: CGRectZero)
        graphView.hostedGraph = newGraph
    }
}
```

When the procedure goes to `graphView.hostedGraph = newGraph` , there will have a fatal error:

***unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value***

Can anybody tell me how to exactly solve this problem?
I know maybe the error happened because I create the new instance of MainController
but I'm very new to iOS development, so I really need to know the detailed procedure to fix it...
BIG Thanks!!!!!!! I'll be very appreciative

I upload my project here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xyghqhyxyy9lm1f/AACfV8JUj7C2Lo3MNcOiGfnIa?dl=0
Could you guys help me to solve this problem? I really need to know......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `graphView` outlet is being released early because of the weak reference. Declare it like this:

```
@IBOutlet var graphView: CPTGraphHostingView!
```

Edit:

I just noticed another problem. The line `MainController().plot(dataOne: [Int], dataTwo: [Int])` creates a new `MainController` object, which doesn't have a reference to the graph view. You need to obtain a reference to the existing view controller and call the `plot` function on it.

Comment: It still has a fatal error, the break point is like this: https://www.flickr.com/photos/136257577@N03/23183175446/in/dateposted-public/
or I'm willing to give my project, I really want to solve this problem. Thank you!!!!

Comment: Does this crash happen on launch or later in the app's lifecycle? Can you tell from the log messages at the bottom of the window where the crash is happening? Be careful with force-unwrapping optionals ("!" vs. "?") because it hides issues that the compiler can otherwise help you find.

Comment: My app always crashes when the procedure goes to 
graphView.hostedGraph = newGraph after I call the function MainController().plot(dataOne: [Int], dataTwo: [Int]). Even I declare like @IBOutlet var graphView: CPTGraphHostingView!, it still crash at the same line. I upload my project here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xyghqhyxyy9lm1f/AACfV8JUj7C2Lo3MNcOiGfnIa?dl=0
Could you help me see where the problem is? I really need to know...

Comment: I downloaded your project and ran it with Xcode 7.1.1. The "TestPlot" button worked fine—it displayed the test graph with no crash.

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't say very clearly. The "TestPlot" button function, "plot" function and the IBOutlet "graphView" are written in the same class (MainController), I just want to test that the core-plot is worked or not with this button. Core-plot is worked well. But my app actually call this "plot" function and refresh the "graphView" is in 'BluetoothManager' class. When I call the function in 'BluetoothManager' class, it would crash like I mentioned before.

Comment: I know, that is my problem! How to reference to the existing VC in different class? I know I use "MainController()" creates new instance different from existing VC , but how to fix it??

Comment: The easiest way is to create an `IBOutlet` in the `BluetoothManager` class and connect it to the view controller in the storyboard.

Comment: I have thought this way before, but my BluetoothManager class isn't the subclass of ViewController. How can I create it and connect it to the BluetoothManager? I'm sorry I have so many questions, I learned Xcode and Swift just for 2 months.

Comment: You could also send a notification from the `BluetoothManager` when it receives new data. Attach the new plot data in the `userInfo` dictionary. If you will be plotting data from device, include a key that identifies the source so the receive knows which plot should display the data. You can also add a key to tell the receiver whether the data is for a new plot or should be added to an existing plot. Have the view controller listen for the data notification and add it to the plot as it comes in.

Comment: Thank for your answer! I've solved it. I instantiate the MainController in ViewDidLoad, then the app worked.